# How display flex and block works?

Tags: html, css

I have two container. Outer container is wrapping inner container.And in inner container is wrapping two dives. For inner container CSS is display flex. For small screen size I mention display block using media quire which is not working.What I am doing wrong.For small screen two div should stacking up.Why media quire not working? When I should give max-width to image?

```css
 .row2{
        display: flex;
        padding:2em 3em;
        }
        .outercontainer{
          background-color: darkgray;
        }
        @media (min-device-width: 426px) and (max-device-width: 764px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
          .row2{
            display: block;
            padding: 0.1em;
            }
            .image2{
              width: 100%;
            }
        }
```

```html
        <div class="outercontainer">
                    <div class="innercontainer row2">
                        <div class="col text">
                            <h3>title text</h3>
                            <p>This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col image">
                        <img class="image2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441974231531-c6227db76b6e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bmF0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Do you want the image to wrap onto the next row underneath the text when the viewport width becomes small?

Comment: Yes. Text on top and Image on next row underneath the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `flex-direction: column` to the Flexbox container `.row2` inside your media query creates a stacked "column" layout at smaller viewports so the image appears underneath the text. The media query `max-width` value might need to bumped up a bit to around 1000px so the [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) column layout happens sooner and the text next to the image doesn't appear squished. Try this out.

Also, the [`device-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width) media feature is deprecated and no longer recommended. Use `min-width` and `max-width` for length values in your media queries instead.

```css
.row2 {
  display: flex;
  padding:2em 3em;
}
.outercontainer {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

/* 764px max-width makes the image squish the text, try around 1000px */
@media (min-width: 426px) and (max-width: 1000px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .row2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0.1em;
  }
  .image2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="innercontainer row2">
      <div class="col text">
          <h3>title text</h3>
          <p>This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col image">
      <img class="image2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441974231531-c6227db76b6e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bmF0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ash What do you mean? The code snippet above works fine. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: I tried it in my code but it didn't work there.

Comment: Then you must have other underlying problems in your code. If your using `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` those media length values are deprecated and the media query won't run. You can see in the code snippet above that it works fine. Make sure you don't have any other styles blocking things.